# Returning two diffrent data types for one method of CrudRepository (findById)

Tags: spring, spring-data

Im using CrudRepository.

I need method findById in two scenarios:

1. EmailShort findById(Long id);
2. EmailFull findById(Long id);

EmailShort and EmailFull are interfaces.

```
public interface EmailFull extends EmailCustom {
    Long getId();

    UserShort getSender();
    String getContent();
    String getTopic();
    String getShortContent();

    @JsonFormat
            (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    Date getCreationTime();
}

public interface EmailShort extends EmailCustom {
    Long getId();

    UserShort getSender();
    String getTopic();
    String getShortContent();
    boolean getIsRead();
    void setRead(boolean read);

    @JsonFormat
            (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    Date getCreationTime();
}
```

My Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EmailDao extends CrudRepository<Email, Long> {

    EmailShort findById(Long id);

    @Query("select e from email e where e.id=?1")
    EmailFull findFullById(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Query(value = "select * " +
            "from email " +
            "where email.id = :emailId", nativeQuery = true)
    EmailShort findByIdWithShortSenderInfo(@Param("emailId") long emailId);
}
```

I can't use Email object, beacuse it contains User with data like address etc (doesn't need it).

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Maybie I should change entities definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use a different name. This is not related to Spring Data at all.

Java decides the method uniqueness based on the signature of the method - name and parameters, not including the return types.

Read up `covariance` and `contravariance` for better understanding, plus this:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I would use projections in this case: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections